# Why don't all my SSIS parallel tasks execute?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a data flow task that is followed by three tasks in the SSIS 2012 package control flow. Part of the data flow is a RowCount transform that sets User::RowCount to the number of rows passed from the data source to the target. After exiting the data flow there are three tasks:

1. An email task - this task runs if Success and User::RowCount>$Project::RowCount_Threshold. This task runs and I get an email (Threshold is set to 1 for testing so I always get an email).
2. A second email task - this task only runs if a secondary task within the data flow detects rows with a value that exceeds a different threshold. If the count of "Issues" (another user variable) exceeds $Project:Issue_Threshold then I get an email. So the condition for executing this task is Success plus the comparison of Issue_Count to Issue_THreshold. This doesn't run and shouldn't since I've set the threshold high right now.
3. The final task takes the User::RowCount and inserts it into a Log Table via an Execute SQL Task with a simple parameterized SQL INSERT. This task runs based only on Success so it should run every time.

My problem is that when I run the package the data flow runs, User::RowCount is set to the number of rows inserted in the target but when the data flow completes only the first task runs. I get the email with the # of rows inserted. The second task shouldn't run based on conditions and it doesn't. The third task should always run but never does. I get no messages, it just doesn't run.

These tasks are configured as parallel tasks following the data flow task.

I've tried everything but haven't been able to figure out why task #3 isn't running. Any ideas?

Picture of the data flow and following tasks:

[image]

The Log Record Count task is the Execute SQL task that isn't running.

Comment: Could you please provide a screen shot of the control flow?

Comment: @Mark Wojciechowicz - diagram added to original post

Comment: it looks like `log record count` is disabled. See how it's a little grey

Comment: @Mark Wojciechowicz - OK. I'm a complete moron. Although in my defense on my display there is virtually no apparent difference between the enabled and disabled tasks. After reading your comment I opened VS and stared at the workflow for a couple of minutes. I can't tell just by looking, I had to right-click on the task to see that the option was "enable", meaning the task was disabled. How do I mark your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add this as the answer:
it looks like `log record count` is disabled. See how it's a little grey

I have to tell you that it is not just your monitor, it's really hard to see the difference.  The SSIS team did a great job improving the debug icons for usability, but this disabled thing needs to be much more obvious.  Put in a connect for it and I'll vote.

m